# Remove placeholders in libreoffice formula editor

Tags: libreoffice, formula-editor

I am trying to use the libreoffice formula editor to add some formulae to drawings in libreoffice draw.

However, whenever I want to enter a formula that LO thinks is wrong it places an ugly upside-down question mark or a box with nothing in it.

MWE:

```
%sigma^+
```

I want to denote the light polarization to be right-circular polarized, hence there should be nothing behind the + sign. However, LO decides a + sign should be followed by something and adds in an ugly placeholder.

In LATEX I would write

```
\sigma^+
```

and be done.

How do I get rid of the placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should type it with double quotes, that is

```
%sigma^"+".
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. Also works for unmatched braces :)